# Copying the date in datetimeformat to a variable in perl

Tags: perl, datetime

How to copy the current date in datetime format to a variable in perl ?

Suppose current date is 2013-05-30 then the value copied to variable

```
$time='2013-05-30 15:10:23'
```

How can I do this in perl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `localtime` and `sprintf`:

```
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime;
my $time = sprintf '%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', 1900+$year, 1+$mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec;
```

Or, using `Time::Piece` (core since 5.9.5):

```
use Time::Piece;
my $time = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

Comment: Yes...this works...but is there anything that is even shorter to include in the code

Comment: @Vishu: See the second option.

Comment: @Vishu `my $date = localtime` will give you a timestamp, although not the format you wanted.